# How to return multiple results for each GROUP BY set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in my database:

1. employee_log
2. job_log
3. crew_log

When a new job is created, an employee is assigned to it, and so an entry is made in the "crew_log" table.

What I am trying to do is to fetch each employee with a type=2 attribute (meaning they are a supervisor) (from employee_log) and then join crew_log, to the query.

Each employee can have multiple active jobs in the "crew_log", so the goal is to return ALL of the active jobs for that employee in an array.

My query so far looks like this:

```
SELECT el.id, cl.job_id
FROM employee_log AS el
JOIN crew_log AS cl
    ON el.id=cl.employee_id
    AND cl.start_date >= CURDATE()
WHERE el.type=2
GROUP BY cl.employee_id
```

It is of course not correct, but maybe it will help visualize my issue.

I can of course do this another way... But I am trying to do everything is one SQL query for both performance and to learn something new about SQL.

The alternative is for me to use two while loops. The first loop will get each employee with type=2, and then within that loop I will do another SQL query to fetch all the active jobs for that employee.

There has to be a better way to do it?

Comment: Please add the structures of the three tables to your question.

Comment: I don't get the requirements themselves. Probably adding some example data from your tables (I guess `job_log` would be unnecesary) and your expected result in a tabular format would help.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks correct as it is, except that you don't need the `GROUP BY` since you don't have any aggregate functions (`SUM(), COUNT(), AVG()`)  Replace it with an `ORDER BY` to sort on the employee id.

```
SELECT el.id, cl.job_id
FROM 
  employee_log AS el
  LEFT JOIN crew_log AS cl
    ON el.id=cl.employee_id
WHERE 
  el.type=2
  AND cl.start_date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY el.id
```

I have also replaced your `JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` so that employees who have no records in `crew_log` are not excluded from the query.